# SFXR-Like Tool for Speech

Tags: tools, sound

Sfxr (and also [Bfxr](http://www.bfxr.net/)) is a great tool for generating sound-effects for games. Is there something like this for speech synthesis?

Not every game development tool and platform has a speech synthesis engine, and it would be great to at least get some decent-sounding placeholders in place to see how the usability/experience plays out. Even better if the results are tweakable, like sfxr.

I'm looking for something I can at least **run on windows,** though preferably (like Bfxr) I would like a **web application** that I can just run out of my browser.

Answer (score 3):

[Festival](http://festvox.org/festival/index.html) has a free software license and one set of voice samples for American English that is also free. It has C++ and Java APIs as well as a Lisp-like command interface.

[Flite](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/) is based on the same principles and is mostly compatible; it has only a C interface and is considerably lighter.

Comment: These look linux-based (I didn't see a binaries download link). I'ml ooking for something web-based, preferably.

Comment: @ashes999 You should probably specifiy that in your question then.

Comment: @Jon done, sorry about that; I thought the reference to Bfxr might have implied it, but now I've made it explicit.

Comment: Festival, at least, does seem to have an 'online demo', as well as release downloads that might contain windows binaries, though it seems to be mostly Unix based.  The links page contains a variety of tools, some of which might be usable.

Comment: Their terms prohibit use of their online demo for anything, really. But you can download and use their app.